# How to delete objects in parse.com after a set amount of time

Tags: android, parse-platform

Basically I want to know how I can delete an object on the server after some amount of time The main idea is to know how to delete an object after some designated time form the server automatically so objects would not persist for a long amount of time.

Thanks.

Comment: Create a piece of cloud code that runs every, say x minutes x hours depending on your need. Assign a deleteAt date to your objects. Have the cloud code query for every object with deleteAt greater than `new Date()` and delete the found objects. That is one way to do it.

Comment: hey could you roughly type that code out since I have no idea about this... thanks

Comment: not easy as it requires you to setup cloud code and stuff. Fortunately parse.com has great tutorials. Getting started with cloud code: https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#cloud_code and then for the code that deletes outdated objects you need a background job https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#jobs. Should be all you need. In case you javascript is rusty, then all of the javascript guide works in cloud code as well.

Comment: I have taken a look at the tutorials yet I'm still quite confused... I took at look at the hello world example and it says that I need to add some additional code to some ambiguous place in order to run the hello world code in the cloud code... Where exactly do i add that code?

Comment: Can you add a link to the part that confuses you?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must create a "job", it's a task you can schedule from your parse.com account.

Here is an example code, it's delete all posts have more 70 days.

```
Parse.Cloud.job('deleteOldPosts', function(request, status) {

    // All access
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var today = new Date();
    var days = 70;
    var time = (days * 24 * 3600 * 1000);
    var expirationDate = new Date(today.getTime() - (time));

    var query = new Parse.Query('post');
        // All posts have more than 70 days
        query.lessThan('createdAt', expirationDate);

        query.find().then(function (posts) {
            Parse.Object.destroyAll(posts, {
                success: function() {
                    status.success('All posts are removed.');
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    status.error('Error, posts are not removed.');
                }
            });
        }, function (error) {});

});
```

You must write this code in your main.js file, follow this steps: https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#started

After your main.js file are upload on parse, you can schedule your job.

[image: Click on Jobs tabs]

It's simple, select your job name in a list and you can plan when the jobs is launch, every hours, every days..

[image]

Comment: I second that above post. Wow! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); has been deprecated in Parse Server version 2.3.0 (Dec 7, 2016).  From that version on, it is a no-op (it does nothing). 
You should now insert the   {useMasterKey:true}  optional parameter to each of the methods that need to override the ACL or CLP in your code.

I ended up using a very similar code to Bluety's code but with some modifications:

```
Parse.Cloud.job('deleteOldActivityLog', function(request, status) {
    var today = new Date();
    var days = 70;
    var time = (days * 24 * 3600 * 1000);
    var expirationDate = new Date(today.getTime() - (time));

    var query = new Parse.Query('ActivityLog');
        // All records created more than 70 days ago
    query.lessThan('createdAt', expirationDate);
    query.each(function(record) {
        return record.destroy({useMasterKey:true});
    },{useMasterKey:true}).then(function(result) {
        console.log("deleteOldActivityLog job completed.");
        status.success("deleteOldActivityLog job completed.");
    }, function(error) {
        alert("Error in deleteOldActivityLog: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        status.error("Error in deleteOldActivityLog: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check if your database can handle the deletion. For instance in MongoDB you can use TTL indexes in order to delete documents after x amount of time.

Please have a look here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/